# Include custom params in rails form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm new in web development and I have the following problem:

I have the following models:

**products**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :steps
end
```

**steps**

```
class Step < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

**products_steps**

```
class ProductsStep < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :step
end
```

I have a form with multiple buttons that should be selected to indicate the steps belonging to the product.

[image: Buttons]

I need send the steps selected as parameter to my product controller, but I don't know how. I was trying use JS to save this informaton but I don't know how can I send it.

```
   function add_h(){
    #detecting if the button is selected or not
    btn_on = document.getElementById("hyd_on");
    btn_off = document.getElementById("hyd_off");
    if(btn_on != null){
      #adding the step related to the selected button
      <% @steps << Step.where(:id => 1) %>
      <% puts "#{@steps.count}" %>
      btn_on.style.background='#686761';
      btn_on.style.border='#686761';
      btn_on.setAttribute("id", "hyd_off");
    }else if (btn_off != null){
      #removing the step
      <% if @steps.count < 0 then @steps.where(:id => 1).first.destroy end %>
      <% puts "#{@steps.count}" %>
      btn_off.style.background='#d463c5';
      btn_off.style.border='#d463c5';
      btn_off.setAttribute("id", "hyd_on");
    }
  }
```

In the controller I'm doing this:

```
 def new
    @product = Product.new()
    @steps = Array.new()
    if Product.all.any?
      @product.id = Product.last.id + 1
    else
      @product.id = 1
    end
  end

def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
end
```

I have the impression that I'm doing everything wrong. I do not know if JS is the best approach but I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is that in a `has_and_belong_to_many` there needs to be a joint table like `model1s_model2s` in the database (the ending s for the plural of the model name). Though there is no need for a specific model for that joint table.

Then I am not sure you need that bit

```
products_steps

class ProductsStep < ApplicationRecord   
belongs_to :product  
belongs_to :step 
end
```

Also you want to create a new product right ?

Then one question: why are you explicitly setting the `product_id` in your `new` action ? your database will set the id when you create a new instance of the Product model. You will definitely face race conditions by setting the id yourself.

Another thing regarding the JS: why ? you can just add different checkboxes that you will design as you want with CSS (color, different color if checked ...). You can give these different checkbox the name of the step : Hydratacao, nutricao ... and check in your `create` action if the param exists `params[:product}[:nutricao].present?` and if present add the relationship for the new product... also you need to collect all steps in the new action and do `@steps = Step.all` instead of `@steps = Array.new()` then in your view you can create the checkboxes by iterating through all the steps you just gathered.

Last thing, in the create action you are instanciating a new object, instead of creating it. You shoud do `@product = Product.create(product_params)` instead of `@product = Product.new(product_params)`. Also you may have to add the steps manually, I am not sure they can be added through the witelisting, but you can try.

(one advice : do the beginner tutorial here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html you will be more familiar with Rest and Crud concepts)

Comment: omg, I completely forgot the checkboxs. But how can I pass the params? Because when I inspect the params the steps aren't present. And  I would like to create an array of steps as parameter, so I need increment that array for each selected checkbox (that's what I'm trying to do with JS). I'm sorry if I'm asking stupid questions, but I'm really newbie in web development

Comment: Each checkbox is an independent param and needs a specific name so that you can retrieve it in the controller. I am not sure you can pass an array to the controller. Just iterate through each step `@steps.each do |step|` `f.checkbox step.name` etc and validate your form. If checkbox is selected your param will appear in controller.